# Instruct VMWare to Ignore certain keys

Tags: keyboard, vmware-workstation

I am wondering if it is possible to have my guest OS in VMWare ignore certain key codes/key strokes. I have certain keys and keystrokes used to change the volume control and switch desktops in the host OS (Debian Linux), and it is annoying to loose those functions when I am using a Guest OS (Windows 7 in this case). I typically run the guest OS in a window (not unity, not full screen, just a normal window like any other application).

I am running VMWare Workstation 9. I see a lot of references online to switching the key mapping in VMWare, and to making VMWare ignore ctrl-alt-del, but I haven't come across this one yet.

The keys, specifically, that I want VMWare to ignore are: XF86AudioRaiseVolume, XF86AudioLowerVolume, XF86AudioMute, as well as 0xc0, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3 (1,2,3, and 4 on a Microsoft split keyboard).

In all other "normal" applications these keys seem to be seen by gnome. For example, pressing volume up in an xterm raises the volume. There's got to be a way to make VMWare do the same thing.

Thanks very much!

--Kc8